# The process to get a observation signal

Tags: compression

First, a small number of active users from a total of K users are set to respectively transmit a frame of convolutionally-encoded binary bits, optionally interleaved, then mapped following the Binary Phase-Shift Keying (BPSK) constellation. Inactive users are set to transmit all-zero frames, thus forming an augmented BPSK constellation {0, ±1}. All frames to be transmitted are then spread using bipolar-valued Pseudo-Noise (PN) spreading sequences before they go through their respective wireless channels (modeled as i.i.d. Rayleigh distributed channels with an exponentially-decaying power delay profile where the expected decay is known). The superposition of these signals through channels is considered to be the observation y the aggregated node or gateway receives

```
enter code here
```

%%%%%%%%%

```
clc
clear
format long;
K=128 ;    % the number of users
Ns=K/4;    %spreading factor
Lh=6;      %channel tap
L=104; 
Pactive=0.02;    %the active possibility of uers
nTx=K*Pactive;  
nBlocks = 10; % number of blocks for each SNR  
SNR = 0:5:25; % dB
X_origin=[];


for iSNR = 1:length(SNR)
    for iBlock = 1:nBlocks
        for i=1:K
            r_K=randperm(L);
            x=zeros(L,1);
            for j=1:nTx
                x(r_K(j))=1;

            end;
            X_origin=[X_origin;x]; % signal vector
          end;
        inSignals=pskmod(X_origin ,2); %bpsk modulation
        cH = RayleighChannel(Ns*L+Lh-1,K*L);  %channel matrix
        rH = RVD(cH);

        cB = cH*inSignals;
        cY = awgn(cB,SNR(iSNR),'measured'); % add noise, n~(0,sigma2) 
        rY = RVD(cY);
        spower = mean(abs(cY(:)).^2);

        cG = cH'*cH;
        rG = rH'*rH;

        sigma2 = spower/(10^(SNR(iSNR)/10));
        cW = cG+eye(K*L)*sigma2;
        rW = RVD(cW);

        invW = inv(rW);

        rYBar = rH'*rY;
        rSHat = invW*rYBar;
        A=rH*rSHat;

        S= CS_gOMP( rY,A,nTx);

        %     X_reconstuction=rSHat*X_r;


        [~,vBer1(iBlock)] = biterr(X_origin,S);

    end;
    %   ber(iSNR) = mean(vBer);
    ber1(iSNR) = mean(vBer1);

    SNR(iSNR)
    ber1(iSNR)
end;
semilogy( SNR,ber1,'go--');
%set(P1,'Linewidth',[2]);
grid on;
title (['\fontsize{12}\bfCS—MUD :\rm','16-QAM,N=',int2str(K*L),',K=',int2str(K)]);
xlabel ('SNR'); ylabel ('BER');
legend('SMV-CS-MUD');
```

Comment: What are your own ideas?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I donot know how to translate it into matlab  so I just randomly generated  vector X constitued by {0,1} ,and do the work Y=H*X+N,  H is what we called channel matrix .and N is the additive noise.  But my teacher want me to redraw the senario